# How do you set the material-ui cardholder avatar?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, avatar

I'm trying to use the material-ui CardHolder component -- https://material-ui.com/api/card-header/ .  I have this image in my project

```
src/img/apple.svg
```

so I tried to set the avatar image like so

```
<Card className={classes.root} {...rest}>
  <CardHeader
    avatar="img/apple.svg"
    title={title}
    titleTypographyProps={{ variant: "h2", component: "span" }}
    className={classes.cardHeader}
  />
  <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
```

but instead what is printed out is just the path of my image.  What's the proper way to output the avatar as a real image?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of [`Avatar`](https://material-ui.com/components/avatars/) component from Material-ui and pass it on as a avatar prop.

the problem in your code is that you are trying to pass on a src to it whereas it takes in a `Node`

```
<Card className={classes.root} {...rest}>
  <CardHeader
    avatar={<Avatar alt="Apple" src="img/apple.svg" />}
    title={title}
    titleTypographyProps={{ variant: "h2", component: "span" }}
    className={classes.cardHeader}
  />
  <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `avatar` prop accepts a node, so you can use [avatar api](https://material-ui.com/components/avatars/) like this one

```
avatar={<Avatar alt="An apple" src="img/apple.svg" />}
```

So your code will become

```
<Card className={classes.root} {...rest}>
  <CardHeader
    avatar={<Avatar alt="An apple" src="img/apple.svg" />}
    title={title}
    titleTypographyProps={{ variant: "h2", component: "span" }}
    className={classes.cardHeader}
  />
  <CardContent className={classes.cardContent}>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure avatar takes an image? From what I can see in the [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/py3x3?file=/demo.js). In the component.

```
avatar={
          <Avatar aria-label="recipe" className={classes.avatar}>
            R
          </Avatar>
        }
```

In the styles:

```
avatar: {
    backgroundColor: red[500],
  },
```

Can't find an image attribute for avatar props.

Comment: Thanks @tksilicon, but what if I have my own image in my project and I want to pass that to the "avatar" argument?